# how to completely remove focus from text field so that it will never gain focus again on IE

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><body>
<input type="text" onFocus="this.blur();" style="outline:none"></input>
</body></html>
```

above code if run in FF then never focus occurs on field and on IE it never works .Thanks for help in advance

i can not use disabled attribute for some reason .

Comment: An input that can never receive focus can be replaced with a span, unless you specifically want it to look like an input (with the border etc.), in which case - why? Why not `disabled`?

Comment: There is probably a better way to accomplish this. If you don't need a text field, then why are you using a text field? Perhaps you could use a hidden field to store a value instead.

Comment: My problem is i am using wicket framework . and if i make my field disable then it will never be the part of form validation as wicket ignores the validation for disabled field . now i want a textfield which will look like disable ,never gain focus . The value on this will be added via a AJAX CALL of wicket

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent IE from showing a colored bar above the input when you hover the mouse over it unless you disable it.

Why does this not work?

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled"></input>
```

Comment: Just thinking, disabled attribute also remove ability to edit input box, right ?

Comment: Yes and so does onFocus="this.blur();" so I assumed that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: My problem is i am using wicket framework . and if i make my field disable then it will never be the part of form validation as wicket ignores the validation for disabled field . now i want a textfield which will look like disable ,never gain focus . The value on this will be added via a AJAX CALL of wicket

Comment: I've dealt with something like this before and ended up using Javascript on the submit event of the form to re-enable all disabled input boxes on the page.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response . In wicket its not recommended to do validation when component onSubmit gets called . so i have not used that , definately this is one solution in my hand . i just need there must be some way by script ,css that we can make a text field disable isn't it?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in IE9. It might slightly highlight the input box but I cannot actually enter text into the box.  Perhaps that is as good as it is going to get.  I doubt you can overcome the IE highlight with CSS or script. Functionality-wise your solution works fine (unless it is different in a previous IE version but I cant test that)

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<input type="text" onFocus="this.blur(),setTimeout(function(){this.blur()},100);" style="outline:none"></input>
```